# Common-Mode or Differential-Mode Choke Circuit

Tags: emc, emi-filtering, common-mode-choke

This circuit, located at the entrance of our power circuits in the products produced in the company I work for, caught my attention. The design of the circuit was completed a long time ago, and now there is no one in the company I can ask questions about what this circuit is used for.

What is the purpose of this circuit seen in the photo below? Is it used for EMI/EMC? How are the design of the circuit and the values of the components around it selected? Is this circuit made to get approval from tests of some industrial standards?

What should I research to find answers to these questions? Where should I start? What books, notes, application notes or articles should I read?

[image: CM-DM Circuit]

Comment: What are the design requirements of the product? Input, standards/regulations, application (I'm guessing, automotive), ratings, etc.? These will dictate the input structure and component values.

Comment: Seems like a ridiculous amount of redundant protection unless this is just some in-between filter thing that can be connected to the outside world from either side. Or it can be something that failed an EMC test and desperate measures were taken to pass, so now they are stuck with them in production.

Comment: These components are mostly for *conducted emissions* and/or *conducted susceptibility*. Conducted Emissions means that your product must limit how much electrical noise it puts onto the Vin bus. Conducted Susceptibility means that your product must still function properly if Vin has electrical noise on it from another source. https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/understanding-electromagnetic-compatibility-tests-conducted-emc/

Comment: @Mattman944 There's not much difference in components when it comes to protecting against conducted vs radiated. Except one tends to prefer metallic encapsulation to handle tough radiated requirements.